# Finding gradient of an implicit function

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, implicit-differentiation

I am having trouble powering through this question, and I think I just need a nudge in the right direction...

Let the function z = f (x,y) be given implicitly by the equation

$x^{3} + xz = z^{3} + 2yz$

Find the gradient of f (x,y) at the point (2,1)

So far I have found the partials to be..

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{3x^{2}+z}{x-3z^{2}-2y}$
and
$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -\frac{2z}{x-3z^{2}-2y}$

But I am unsure if those are correct.

Comment: Check the $-$ sign for $\partial z /\partial y$.

Comment: ah yes. that part is positive. so $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{3x^{2}+z}{x-3z^{2}-2y}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{3x^{2}+z}{x-3z^{2}-2y}$

Comment: So for the gradient, I use $ \nabla f(x,y) = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\vec i + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\vec j $. Doesnt this mean when I plug in my point of (2,1) my vector will have z terms in it though?

Comment: Use $x^{3} + xz = z^{3} + 2yz$ to compute the value of $z$ for $(x,y)=(2,1)$.

Comment: Okay. so z = 2. So my gradient, $\nabla f(x,y) = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\vec i + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\vec j $, becomes $\nabla f(x,y) = -\frac{3x^{2}+2}{x-12-2y}\vec i + \frac {4}{x-12-2y}\vec j$. Plugging in my point of (2,1,2) gives me $\frac{7}{6}\vec i - \frac {1}{3}\vec j$